# Creating a Facebook event on public FB Page using iPhone SDK Graph API

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I'm trying to let users create an event on my public Facebook page via an iPhone app, and hopefully let ppl invite their friends to that event.
The idea is that the iPhone app will be able to show the users events from that page, while everyone is able to add the events.

After Authorizing with permissions: create_event and manage_pages, i'm trying to run the following code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       @"My Event",@"name",
                                       PAGE_ID, @"page_id",
                                       @"2011-11-10T13:30",@"start_time",
                                       @"2011-11-11T13:30",@"end_time", nil];

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/events", PAGE_ID]
                    andParams:params
                andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                 andDelegate:self];
```

And I get and error saying: "(#200) Permissions error".
Is it even possible? (creating an event on a page which a user doesn't own)
and if so, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"offline_access", @"user_events",@"create_event",@"rsvp_event", nil];
```

I hope that it is just your help.